# Angular 4/6 material slider, time scale sliders for 24 hours

Tags: angular, angular-material

I am using Angular Material to create a slider. This slider is for 24 hours and I want to display the value of slider on the side. 
The following things are working:

1. Getting the value of slider on change with `(change)` event
   .html

```html
<mat-slider style="width:50%" thumbLabel name="range1" #timeSlider type="range" tickInterval="1" step="0.5" min="1" max="24"
                (change)="onChangeRange(timeSlider.value)">
</mat-slider>
```

.ts

```ts
onChangeRange(rangeValue: any) {
  console.log(rangeValue);
  this.showTime = rangeValue;
}
```

Issues:

1. I want to show the value of selected in form of time `HH:mm`, also below is interpolation I tried to use to convert `type: number` value in time format but nothing is working

```html
<button mat-raised-button class="displayTimeBtn">
  <span>
    {{showTime}}
    <!-- {{showTime | date:"shortTime"}} -->
  </span>
</button>
```

2. I also want to change the display of "thumb label"

What it looks like as of now:

[image: Current slider]

Comment: Please add this comment in your question, not in comment.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You just need to use the `displayWith` attribute of mat-slider to format the thumb label. So, update your template code to:

```html
<mat-slider thumbLabel [displayWith]="formatLabel" tickInterval="1" step="0.5"
  min="1" max="24" (change)="onChangeRange($event)">
</mat-slider>
```

Where formatLabel method can be:

```ts
 formatLabel(value: number | null) {
    if (!value) {
      return 0;
    }

    let decimalPart = +value.toString().replace(/^[^\.]+/,'0');
    let mm = decimalPart * 60;
    var mmPart = mm.toString().length == 1 ? mm.toString() + "0" : mm.toString();

    if (value >= 0) {
      let valueStr = value.toFixed(2);
      let strArr = valueStr.split(".");
      if(strArr[0].length == 1) {
        strArr[0] = "0" + strArr[0];
      }
      var hhPart = strArr[0];
    }

    return hhPart + ":" + mmPart;
 }
```

Now you can use whatever formatted or non-formatted value as model value.

[Example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-cvdb7f?file=app%2Fslider-formatting-example.ts)

Comment: Thank you @Shantanu for the answer, but I am not able to see anything in a demo.

Comment: @jay Are you opening the link in chrome? Are you behind any corporate proxy? Because there may be some scripts are not loading. Because I'm able to view this stackblitz app

Comment: I was able to open the solution and it Works perfectly fine. but I still have one more question, that right now at half n hour it shows current value 01:50 or 07:50(I know that It is because how I have set it up right now). but because this scale is for time, How can I change it to  01:30 or 07:30 type format? 
Once again Thanks a lot for your help @shantanu.

Comment: @jay check updated code & updated example. I've updated the decimal part to be like minutes values. So for any stepsize of slider it'll work as expected

Comment: This is perfect . Thanks a lot for your help. I have tried a lot to find something slimier as in time scale slider but couldn't find anything. I think this is a great help for other's also. Thanks again.